# LazyLoad is not a function

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading

I am getting error, *lazyload is not a function*

But jquery and lazyload is loaded BEFORE calling the function. And I checked, and there is only one jQuery loaded.The order of the loading is working.

http://meny.astadvingard.se/vin/varugrupp/sott-vin/tillganglighet/vinbar/

Very strange, also checked with Chrome Inspector - in which gives me the error.
I know I have to use data-original etc with the img-tag later – but right now I just want the lazyload to BE A FUNCTION.

Comment: I'm also struggling with this one on a very slow to load page. (huge data)
not sure if it a race condition somehow as I got it to work once and not again since

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have a `ready state` inside a `ready state`? Change:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    console.log($, 'jquery works');
    $(function(){
        console.log($("img.lazy").length);
        $("img.lazy").lazyload();
    });
});
```

To:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    console.log($, 'jquery works');
    console.log($("img.lazy").length);
    $("img.lazy").lazyload();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Eisbehr, updated that – but that does not solve the lazyload is not a function.

Answer (score -1):

Use jquery.lazyload.js

By referring jquery.lazyload.js file before the LazyLoad.js, it will resolve your issue.

You can download it from [here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery.lazyload)

[Content Delivery Network](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.lazyload/1.9.1/jquery.lazyload.js)